# Inconsistent changing tkinter button relief after it is placed. Python 3.7. Windows 10

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a button look like it's already been selected by changing its color and relief. When I do it this way the color consistently changes correctly but the relief doesn't always. Mainly on the first click  (perhaps always the first click).

```
from tkinter import *

def change_button(event):
    if event.widget['bg'] == 'blue':
        event.widget.configure(bg='red',relief='sunken')
        print(event.widget['bg'],event.widget['relief'])
    else:
        event.widget.configure(bg='blue',relief='raised')
        print(event.widget['bg'],event.widget['relief'])

root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x200')
b = Button(root,text='Hello World',bg='blue',width=30,height=2)
b.bind('<Button-1>',change_button)
b.place(relx=.5,rely=.5,anchor='center')

root.mainloop()
```

[image: Here is both the idle output and a few screen grabs.]

As you can see the output always says sunken when the button is red but that isn't the case in the GUI.
I've tried root.update() and root.update_idletasks() but that doesn't help.

Comment: I tried it and it works the way it is supposed to if I hold the button for a bit. Btw consider changing the text inside the button instead of the background - it will be easier to see.

Comment: Perhaps your changes are conflicting with the relief changes that the built-in Button click binding is trying to do.  You could add `return "break"` to the end of your handler to prevent any other handlers from being called.

Comment: Jason you seem to be correct that the built-in click binding is conflicting with my relief change. For whatever reason it doesn't conflict on the color change though. My solution is to configure the button command rather than bind the click event.`b.configure(command=partial(change_button,b))`. The change button function is changed to take the widget rather than event as the argument. Partial is from functools by the way.